# how to convert hash string to md5 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, hmac

This is my first time working on HMAC,
I have this method to create hash string for HMAC:

```
    var msg = method + publicKey + path + privateKey
    //like:
   var msg = 'GET' + 'MY-PUBLIC-KEY' + '/api/account' + 'MY_PRIVATE_KEY';
```

I'm using [this](http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5.js) library for converting msg to md5. 
in the backend code I see

```
string expectedValue = Hashing.GetHashHMACCMD5OfString(msg, PublicKey)

....

public static string GetHashHMACCMD5OfString(string value, string key)
{
    using (var cryptoProvider = new HMACMD5(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)))
    {
        var hash = cryptoProvider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
}
```

I don't know about .net, is it enough just to convert msg as

```
var md5Msg = md5(msg, publickey);
// and request
$http({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authentication': md5Msg + ' ' + publickey 
  }
});
```

in javascript or I need any other conversion (like toBase64) to do?

Comment: Just some background on MD5 http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: It's not entirely clear what interaction there is between your javascript and .net code here.  Do you want to use the .Net MD5 hashing code via an ajax call?  Also - I agree with @JohnHartsock.  Be sure that MD5 is necessary for your use, and consider an alternative.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes. I'm using AngularJs and in the Xhr request, as you can see, for Authenticating the client I need to use HMAC. the issue is when I covert msg to md5Msg as mentioned, the result is different from expected value which I get in the response (responds expected value for dev mode)